# Magento data migration error: Undefined index: dest

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

When I run the migrate:data command I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: dest in
>   /var/www/html/magetno/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src
>   /Migration/Step/Eav/InitialData.php on line 161

Checked the given file and the error comes from the following method:

```
public function getAttributes($type)
{
    return $this->attributes[$type];
}
```

I also checked the database of magento 1 site and there is no attribute with code 'dest'

**Edit:**

Checked on further and found its coming from data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php line 421

```
$destinationRecords = $this->initialData->getAttributes('dest');
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this issue at all as I am also running into this :)

Comment: Hi, and how did you resolve the issue?

Comment: This issue is not yet resolved. Have posted the same issue on their GitHub repo also.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your destination EAV tables have data in. I ran into this issue when attempting to migrate to a schema with no initial data in.

If you look at vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/InitialData.php on line 108, when initialising the attributes the 'dest' index will not be set if you have no attributes in your EAV table.

```
        foreach ($destinationRecords as $id => $record) {
            $this->attributes['dest'][$id] = $record;
        }
```

A simple fix is to ensure you've run the Magento 2 install for your site before running the migration, which will add the base attributes for you.